# Preact log performance after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to log out the time taken in preact to update a component and render it.

Here is the code :

```
handleKeyPress(event) {
    renderingTime = Date.now()
    ...
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    if (renderingTime) {
        console.log('finished rendering ' + (Date.now() - renderingTime))
        this.onNextFrame(function() {
            console.log('finished rendering anim ' + (Date.now() - renderingTime))
        })
    }
}

onNextFrame(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)
    }, 0)
}
```

Then I get the trace from Cobalt browser (a bit like Chromium). In this trace i can see that the "finished rendering" log gives me the javascript execution time. The "finished rendering anim" log gives me the javascript execution time + the layout time.

Then I see on the trace that there is the rasterizer part from the media_pipeline that is still happening afterward.

Is there a way to get this part included in my measurement ?
I need these measurements to run automated tests and so need the result in the console logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React Performance tool](https://github.com/nitin42/react-perf-devtool)

You can measure performance of react app

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I am using preact and need the output in the console for automated tests.